# How to get Android Webview(Chromium Engine) Release note for all android release

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I am looking for release notes of Chromium engine which was supported as a part of android webview.

Thanks,
Mayank

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reference the README file in the android source code of `external/chromium-webview/` as follows:

http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/external/chromium-webview/

```
Building the Chromium-based WebView in AOSP is no longer supported. WebView can
now be built entirely from the Chromium source code.

General instructions for building WebView from Chromium:
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/build-instructions-android-webview

------

The prebuilt libwebviewchromium.so included in these APKs is built from Chromium
release tag 51.0.2704.91, using the GN build tool (not the older GYP tool). To match our build settings, set:

target_os="android"
is_debug=false
is_official_build=true
is_chrome_branded=false
use_official_google_api_keys=false
exclude_unwind_tables=true
enable_resource_whitelist_generation=true
ffmpeg_branding="Chrome"
proprietary_codecs=true
enable_remoting=true
android_chrome_build_id="c212fd71-e1d3-4b49-9f08-878f16747dd9"

in your GN argument file before building.

------

Due to WebView API changes in the N release, the Java code in the Chromium 2704_81
branch is not compatible with N. We'll be working on upstreaming the N-specific
Java changes to Chromium once the final N SDK is released.

------

For questions about building WebView, please see
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/android-webview-dev
```